# A function relating $k$ and $j$, where $k=\max_{l\in \mathbb{N}}\sum_{i=0}^{l}2^{n-i}\leq j$ and $n= \lfloor \log_{2}j \rfloor$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Do you know any function that relates k and j, where $k=\max_{l\in \mathbb{N}}\sum_{i=0}^l 2^{n-i}\leq j$ and $n=\lfloor \log_2 j \rfloor$?

So, say, for $j=3$:

$n=1$ and $k=1$ because $3\geq 2+2^{1-1}$.

i.e. a function $f(j)=k$ or $g(k)=j$.

Basically, I have a formula that contains both j,k and I need an expression of k in terms of j. So my formula will not have k in it. I don't know ,say, my formula is $a=b+jk$ and the expression is $j=2k$, then $a=b+\frac{j^{2}}{2}$.

Thanks

**Update**
Inspired by Did's response.

In this paper they give expressions for the number of ones in the binary expansion of n
http://www.emis.de/journals/JIS/VOL12/Ruskey2/ruskey14.pdf

That is what I mean by "function".

I am looking for a function that gives number of 1's up to fist zero in the binary expansion of j. eg. to get some g s.t. $g(13)=g(1101_{2})=2-1=1$. And so it would give us g(j)-1=k.

1) a generating function for the number of 1's in a binary expansion eg. $1(13)=1(1101_{2})=3$. Then maybe I can work it, to get to what I want.

2)if we can get m(n) that gives position of the first zero eg. $m(13)=3$ and so $m(n)-1=k$.

Comment: The desired function is neither the number of 1's in the binary expansion nor this number minus one, please reread my answer.

Comment: i know, that's why I said "even better". I should have been more explicit. The function g is the desired one.

Comment: The position of the first zero of the expansion of 13 starting from the right is 2, not 3. If one counts the position of the first zero from the left then the total number of digits is irrelevant. You lost me (or, should you read my answer more carefully?).

Comment: Funny, my username disappeared from your Update... Rewriting history?

Comment: are you always that rude/pedantic to people who ask questions? I agree with your comments but no need to decorate them.

Comment: Pffff... [Again](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/883872/6179)? More to the point, the construction I explain in my post shows that the hope of "a formula eg. j=2k" (whatever the precise meaning one gives to it) should be abandoned. But really, this comes from some overly narrow idea of what a "formula" is (oops, Nasty Me being too "rude/pedantic" again, perhaps...).

Comment: All I am wondering is, if there is a way to get k, without having to explicitly count the number of initial ones in the binary expansion of j. And if not, I would like to know why. For example, in this paper they give expressions for number of ones emis.de/journals/JIS/VOL12/Ruskey2/ruskey14.pdf.

Comment: You mean, to compute the **generating function** (in the usual sense of the term) $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{+\infty}k(j)x^j$, perhaps? (Unrelated: I see you edited heavily this thread of comments. This is a good thing, in a way, but you might want to delete still another one.)

Answer (score 0):

For every positive integer $j$, the number of initial ones in the binary expansion of $j$ is $k+1$.

For example, the binary expansion of $j=117=2^6+2^5+2^4+2^2+2^0$ is $1\color{red}{11}0101$ hence $k=\color{red}{2}$.

Comment: nice, but I am looking for sth in a function form. Could this be worked into one somehow?

Comment: Please define "function form".

Comment: i mean a generating function. if I plug in j=117, I get 2 out of it.

Comment: This reports the problem on knowing what you call a "generating function" (which seems to be something else than the usual). To write down the binary expansion of $j$, to pick the length of the initial segment of ones, to subtract 1 to it and to call this $k$ **is to define a function** $j\mapsto k$.

Comment: I am looking for a formula eg. j=2k.

Comment: See comment to main question.